# Selecting, filtering and aggregating in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

if we have two dataset 1-First dataset contains population data of cities in the United States of America. Each record in the dataset has the following format:

```
{
     "city": "ACMAR",
     "loc": [
         -86.51557,
         33.584132
     ],
     "pop": 6055,
     "state": "AL",
     "_id": "35004"
}
```

Second dataset contains log data from a geo-locational service. Each record in the dataset has the following format:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5191f53b1b76a5666a8cbd64"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "requrest_time": 504,   // in milliseconds
    "type": "stationboard",
    "datetime": {
        "$date": "2014-02-19T07:03:32.000Z"
    }
}
```

1. how we can get all the states that have at least 2 cities with population > 1000000 (1M). And we need to  remember that city can be split into multiple records, and we should aggregate its population first. (zips dataset)
2. we need find a day (date) with the largest number of HTTP 500 errors (status=500).

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest you take a look at the MongoDB aggregation framework.

Comment: i have done it ,but not sure if it is correct .

Comment: Add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: "remember that city can be split into multiple records" -> a single *city* can have more than 1 record?

Answer (score 1):

> how we can get all the states that have at least 2 cities with
>   population > 1000000 (1M). And we need to remember that city can be
>   split into multiple records, and we should aggregate its population
>   first. (zips dataset)

I have `zips` collection database having `29353` records.

```
> db.zips.find().count()
29353
> db.zips.count()
29353
```

and the documents structure inside the `collection` is such as

```
> db.zips.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : "01007",
        "city" : "BELCHERTOWN",
        "loc" : [
                -72.410953,
                42.275103
        ],
        "pop" : 10579,
        "state" : "MA"
}
{
        "_id" : "01002",
        "city" : "CUSHMAN",
        "loc" : [
                -72.51565,
                42.377017
        ],
        "pop" : 36963,
        "state" : "MA"
}
{
        "_id" : "01008",
        "city" : "BLANDFORD",
        "loc" : [
                -72.936114,
                42.182949
        ],
        "pop" : 1240,
        "state" : "MA"
}
{
        "_id" : "01011",
        "city" : "CHESTER",
        "loc" : [
                -72.988761,
                42.279421
        ],
        "pop" : 1688,
        "state" : "MA"
}
{
        "_id" : "01010",
        "city" : "BRIMFIELD",
        "loc" : [
                -72.188455,
                42.116543
        ],
        "pop" : 3706,
        "state" : "MA"
}
```

which is the same as mention documents structure by the `OP`.

```
{
     "city": "ACMAR",
     "loc": [
         -86.51557,
         33.584132
     ],
     "pop": 6055,
     "state": "AL",
     "_id": "35004"
}
```

Suppose that here i want to write an `aggregation` query with a single match phase that **`filters`** for `zipcodes` with greater than `100,000` people.

Here i will write down the simple query with $match (aggregation) and Operator [$pop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) to filter the documents.
[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.

```
> db.zips.aggregate([{$match:{pop:{$gt:100000}}}])
{ "_id" : "10021", "city" : "NEW YORK", "loc" : [ -73.958805, 40.768476 ], "pop" : 106564, "state" : "NY" }
{ "_id" : "10025", "city" : "NEW YORK", "loc" : [ -73.968312, 40.797466 ], "pop" : 100027, "state" : "NY" }
{ "_id" : "11226", "city" : "BROOKLYN", "loc" : [ -73.956985, 40.646694 ], "pop" : 111396, "state" : "NY" }
{ "_id" : "60623", "city" : "CHICAGO", "loc" : [ -87.7157, 41.849015 ], "pop" : 112047, "state" : "IL" }
>
```

In the above example i have found out the 4 states and their respective cities . Where population is `> 100000`.

> we need find a day (date) with the largest number of HTTP 500 errors
>   (status=500).

For spherical queries, use the 2dsphere index result.

As MongoDB documented [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/) The use of `2d` index for spherical queries may lead to incorrect results, such as the use of the `2d` index for spherical queries that wrap around the poles.

MongoDB geospatial queries on  [`GeoJSON`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-geojson) objects calculate on a sphere; MongoDB uses the [WGS84](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-wgs84) reference system for geospatial queries on `GeoJSON` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.part1zips.aggregate([
  { $part1 :
    {
      _id : { state : "$state", city : "$city" },
      pop : { $sum : "$pop" } 
    }
  },
  { $match : { pop: { $gte : 1000000 } } },
  { $group :
    {
      _id: "$_id.state",
      no_st: { $sum : 1 } 
    }
  },
  { $match : { no_st: { $gte: 2 } } }       
])
```

---

```js
db.part2logs.aggregate([
  { $match: { status: 500} },
  { $group: 
    { 
      _id: {
        year : { $year : "$datetime" },        
        month : { $month : "$datetime" },        
        day : { $dayOfMonth : "$datetime"}
        },
      noerr:  { $sum: 1 } }
    },
  { $sort: { noerr: -1} },  
  { $limit : 1 }
])
```